# How to properly make a Docker Compose that is placed in a different path from the project/dockerfile?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml file should be placed on the root folder of the 'solution' so it can execute multiple projects at once when debugging(I'm on Visual Studio).

This is my docker-compose which is in the root directory of our solution(D:\repos\MySolution):

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./MyAngularProject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

And here is my Dockerfile which is in one of project folders inside the solution(D:\repos\MySolution\MyAngularProject):

```
FROM node:12.10.0    
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8
COPY . /app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

With the WORKDIR in the Dockerfile, it should execute `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` in the `/app` directory. But I receive this error:

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

I tried to create a different docker-compose file in my angular project(D:\repos\MySolution\MyAngularProject) with this content and it works properly:

```
version: '3.7'    
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely related to the volumes on your `docker-compose.yml` file.

The build part of `Dockerfile` runs fine as it has no knowledge of volumes. When you then mount volumes over an existing directory in the container (/app in this case) you won’t be able to see the files that were previously built there, but the files in the folder you just mounted instead. This is expected and consistent with Linux mount behavior.

That said, when you mount `./` into `/app` in your `docker-compose.yml`, the only thing inside `/app` when the `CMD` command runs is a folder called `MyAngularProject`, instead of the angular project definition and other files that were there before.

When you move the `docker-compose.yml` into `MyAngularProject`, the behavior is exactly the same, but now it’s mounting a folder that has what `CMD` needs to run.

Thus, removing the `./:/app` volume mapping in `docker-compose.yml` shall solve the issue.